# Como crio lista que ao clicar chame a função enviando um valor?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou usando um `Select` para passar valores para uma função em JavaScript.

Quando selecionado pega o `value` e com base nesse valor a função que tenho aqui retorna algo.

Queria trocar por uma lista de links que ao clicar faça a mesma coisa.

Esse é o código que tenho:

```
       <select id="linha" onclick="selectBus()">
            <option value="1">item1</option>
            <option value="2">item1</option> 
            <option value="3">item1</option>
        </select>
```

Isso já funciona com o `Select`, mas gostaria de trocar por uma lista de links.

Comment: use o evento `onchange`

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="linha">
    <option value="1">item1</option>
    <option value="2">item1</option> 
    <option value="3">item1</option>
</select>

<script>
    $(function(){
        // ao selecionar um serviço abre o combo de tipo
        $('#linha').on('change', function () {
            // Recupera o value do option
            var LinhaID = $(this).val();
            // Após você pode chamar uma ou mais funções
            funcao01();
            funcao02(LinhaID);
        });
    });

    function funcao01(){ /* coloque seu código aqui*/ }
    function funcao02(id){
        alert('O value selecionado é: ' + id);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Wilson, talvez não fui tão claro. Hoje ja tenho um Select funcionando com o Javascript no onclick, tudo blz!! Porém ao invés de usar um Select quero usar <a href></a> , que ao clicar ele execute minha função do Javascript. Obrigado

Comment: veja se é isso: <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="minhaFuncao();">clique</a>

Comment: oi wilson, não funcionou

Comment: faça o seguinte, coloque os códigos completos HTML e a selectBus() para melhor analisarmos blz.